# How to safely remove Exim4 on CentOS?

Tags: centos, exim

I am trying to install Postfix and remove the Exim4. How should I safely do it?

Comment: Without further information this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `yum`:

`sudo yum remove exim4`

Comment: Thanks and I found that `rpm -e exim` can also remove the exim

Comment: Yes you can use rpm as well. I prefer yum only because when you use a package manager like yum, you have better control of the packages you want to update as opposed to using rpm or even compiling from source